# Remove substring between certain characters

Tags: ruby, string

I was wondering if there was a way to remove everything between two carrots from a string:

```
"<@000000> I thought you said this would happen?"
```

to get:

```
"I thought you said this would happen?"
```

I thought using global substitution would work. I attempted with this code:

```
somefile = File.open("Test_Teleó.txt", "a+")
  jdoc.fetch("messages").each do |body|
    ts = body["ts"].to_i
    somefile.puts body["text"].gsub(/[<]/, '').gsub(/[>]/, '').chomp
  end
```

And the output is:

```
@000000 I thought you said this would happen?
```

It only removed the carrots and not the between characters.

Any advice?

Comment: By "carrots" I presume you mean `<>` (angle brackets) and not ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you tried that only removed the characters, but didn't do what you wanted?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: If you only want to remove the first instance of the pattern, consider using `String#sub` instead of `String#gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor adjustment of your code is required:

```
File.open("Test_Teleó.txt", "a+") do |somefile|
  jdoc.fetch("messages").each do |body|
    ts = body["ts"].to_i
    somefile.puts body["text"].gsub(/<[^>]*>/, '').chomp 
  end
end
```

I've also use the block-style `open` here since that will automatically close the file when the block completes. This helps avoid forgetting and leaving files open by accident.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the significance of this `^>`. I'm also wondering if I can do an `and` statement that would allow other things that must be replaced by nothing. For instance: I want to simplify this `body["text"].gsub(/<[^>]*>/, '').gsub(/[\n]/, '').gsub(/[,]/, '').chomp`.

Comment: Inside of "set notation", the `[...]` part in a regular expression, a leading caret (`^`) means "inverse", as in `[^>]` means "any not angle close bracket character". This prevents the regular expression from going berserk when encountering text like `"<1>A<2>B<3>C"` and grabbing `<1...3>` as if that was one tag. The "not" part means it must stop at `1>`.